# Extract a substring according to a pattern

Tags: regex, r, substr

Suppose I have a list of string:

```
string = c("G1:E001", "G2:E002", "G3:E003")
```

Now I hope to get a vector of string that contains only the parts after the colon ":", i.e `substring = c(E001,E002,E003)`.

Is there a convenient way in R to do this? Using `substr`?

Answer (score 316, accepted):

Here are a few ways:

**1) sub**

```
sub(".*:", "", string)
## [1] "E001" "E002" "E003"
```

**2) strsplit**

```
sapply(strsplit(string, ":"), "[", 2)
## [1] "E001" "E002" "E003"
```

**3) read.table**

```
read.table(text = string, sep = ":", as.is = TRUE)$V2
## [1] "E001" "E002" "E003"
```

**4) substring**

This assumes second portion always starts at 4th character (which is the case in the example in the question):

```
substring(string, 4)
## [1] "E001" "E002" "E003"
```

**4a) substring/regex**

If the colon were not always in a known position we could modify (4) by searching for it:

```
substring(string, regexpr(":", string) + 1)
```

**5) strapplyc**

`strapplyc` returns the parenthesized portion:

```
library(gsubfn)
strapplyc(string, ":(.*)", simplify = TRUE)
## [1] "E001" "E002" "E003"
```

**6) read.dcf**

This one only works if the substrings prior to the colon are unique (which they are in the example in the question).  Also it requires that the separator be colon (which it is in the question).  If a different separator were used then we could use `sub` to replace it with a colon first.  For example, if the separator were `_` then `string <- sub("_", ":", string)`

```
c(read.dcf(textConnection(string)))
## [1] "E001" "E002" "E003"
```

**7) separate**

**7a)** Using `tidyr::separate` we create a data frame with two columns, one for the part before the colon and one for after, and then extract the latter.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

DF <- data.frame(string)
DF %>% 
  separate(string, into = c("pre", "post")) %>% 
  pull("post")
## [1] "E001" "E002" "E003"
```

**7b)** Alternately `separate` can be used to just create the `post` column and then `unlist` and `unname` the resulting data frame:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

DF %>% 
  separate(string, into = c(NA, "post")) %>% 
  unlist %>%
  unname
## [1] "E001" "E002" "E003"
```

**8) trimws** We can use `trimws` to trim word characters off the left and then use it again to trim the colon.

```
trimws(trimws(string, "left", "\\w"), "left", ":")
## [1] "E001" "E002" "E003"
```

### Note

The input `string` is assumed to be:

```
string <- c("G1:E001", "G2:E002", "G3:E003")
```

Comment: I had a variable in a melted table that had `_` as a separator and made two separate variables for the prefix and suffix based on @Grothendieck answer:  `prefix <- sub("_.*", "", variable)` and 
`suffix <- sub(".*_", "", variable)`

Comment: It would be nice to see a microbenchmarking of this amazing answer!

Comment: A slightly more generic version of 4a which can handle different patterns, including those with regex characters: `rightOf <- function(pattern, string) {substring(string, regexpr(pattern, string, fixed = T) + nchar(pattern))}`

Answer (score 30):

For example  using `gsub` or `sub`

```
    gsub('.*:(.*)','\\1',string)
    [1] "E001" "E002" "E003"
```

Comment: could you explaon what these ' . * ( * and so on do there exactly? I'm having a hard time recreating this in an only slightly different setting...

Comment: @PeterPan This captures and returns the group of characters appearing after the colon. If the strings to match are more complicated and you want to stay in base R this works well.

Answer (score 16):

Late to the party, but for posterity, the **stringr** package (part of the popular "tidyverse" suite of packages) now provides functions with harmonised signatures for string handling:

```
string <- c("G1:E001", "G2:E002", "G3:E003")
# match string to keep
stringr::str_extract(string = string, pattern = "E[0-9]+")
# [1] "E001" "E002" "E003"

# replace leading string with ""
stringr::str_remove(string = string, pattern = "^.*:")
# [1] "E001" "E002" "E003"
```

Comment: Isn't this finding the first number that starts with an E, rather than everything after the colon?

Answer (score 15):

Here is another simple answer

```
gsub("^.*:","", string)
```

Answer (score 8):

This should do:

```
gsub("[A-Z][1-9]:", "", string)
```

gives

```
[1] "E001" "E002" "E003"
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are using `data.table` then `tstrsplit()` is a natural choice:

```
tstrsplit(string, ":")[[2]]
[1] "E001" "E002" "E003"
```

Answer (score 6):

The *unglue* package provides an alternative, no knowledge about regular expressions is required for simple cases, here we'd do :

```r
# install.packages("unglue")
library(unglue)
string = c("G1:E001", "G2:E002", "G3:E003")
unglue_vec(string,"{x}:{y}", var = "y")
#> [1] "E001" "E002" "E003"
```

<sup>Created on 2019-11-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

More info : https://github.com/moodymudskipper/unglue/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 5):

Another method to extract a substring

```
library(stringr)
substring <- str_extract(string, regex("(?<=:).*"))
#[1] "E001" "E002" "E003
```

- `(?<=:)`: look behind the colon (`:`)

Comment: would you know how this can be adapted to a character that occurs after the pattern, 
something like `(:=>?`) ? (which did not work)

Answer (score 4):

Surprisingly, a base R solution has not yet been added:

```r
string = c("G1:E001", "G2:E002", "G3:E003")

regmatches(string, regexpr('E[0-9]+', string))
```