# Getting a sub string from a vector of strings

Tags: r, substring

I have a vector of strings

```
ids <- c("NM_006690.2_PROBE1","333212.1_PROBE1","7602049CB1_PROBE1","NM_018065.1_PROBE1","1539036CB1_PROBE1","NM_021019.1_PROBE1","1440608CB1_PROBE1","NM_031270.1_PROBE1","613678CB1_PROBE1")
```

A lot of discussing is already here: [extract a substring in R according to a pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17215789/extract-a-substring-in-r-according-to-a-pattern).

I want to remove everything after a `dot(.)` and  want to remove all after `_` before `PROBE`. i managed to remove `.` by

```
read.table(text = ids, sep = ".", as.is = TRUE, fill=TRUE)$V1
```

I now mind to remove the  `_` before PROBE  in cases like `613678CB1_PROBE1` and the output i want is `613678CB1`  . How to do it.

Output:

```
"NM_006690", "333212"  , "7602049CB1"  "NM_018065","1539036CB1"  "NM_021019" "1440608CB1"  "NM_031270","613678CB1")
```

Note: There are two `_`'s one attached with `NM` and other with `PROBE`. I want the one every thing to be removed  `_PROBE`

Comment: It would be better if you post the expected output.  For the first case, do you need `NM_`

Comment: @akrun . check updates

Comment: Also please test your code before posting it.   The `ids <- ` line has syntax errors.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck, may i know the syntax error.

Comment: The error is what you get when you enter the erroneous code into R but it seems someone has fixed the question for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like you're asking for:

```
gsub("\\..*|_PROBE.*", "", ids)
```

Demo:

```
gsub("\\..*|_PROBE.*", "", ids)
# [1] "NM_006690"  "333212"     "7602049CB1" "NM_018065"  "1539036CB1"
# [6] "NM_021019"  "1440608CB1" "NM_031270"  "613678CB1"
```

Answer (score 2):

do you just want this?

```
ids <- c("NM_006690.2_PROBE1", "333212.1_PROBE1"  , "7602049CB1_PROBE1" , "NM_018065.1_PROBE1",
         "1539036CB1_PROBE1",  "NM_021019.1_PROBE1", "1440608CB1_PROBE1",  "NM_031270.1_PROBE1",
         "613678CB1_PROBE1")
ids <- read.table(text = ids, sep = ".", as.is = TRUE, fill=TRUE)$V1

library(stringr)
ids <- str_replace(ids, "_PROBE1", "")
```

which gives you this:

```
"NM_006690"  "333212"     "7602049CB1" "NM_018065"  "1539036CB1" "NM_021019"  "1440608CB1" "NM_031270"  "613678CB1"
```

Comment: @akrun, I don't think that the OP has posted correct input or output data.

Comment: yeah there is one more step in between which he does, so the first two lines are actually the input-data with the transformation the op did beforehand... I edited my post