# Split row names by “.” character and put in new columns in r

Tags: r, split

Input:

```
df = data.frame(1:3)
rownames(df) <- c("a.bzz.-11", "bb.c.44", "cdd.d.3")
```

Expected output:

```
            X1.5    col1    col2    col3
a.bzz.-11   1      a        bzzz    -11
bb.c.44      2     bb       c       44
cdd.d.3     3      cdd      d       3
```

There are few interesting discussions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17215789/extract-a-substring-in-r-according-to-a-pattern) but not working in my case. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `read.table` to read the row names into the three column by using the delimiter as `.`.

```
cbind(df, read.table(text=row.names(df), sep=".", 
          header=FALSE, col.names = paste0("col", 1:3), stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
#          X1.3 col1 col2 col3
#a.bzz.-11    1    a  bzz  -11
#bb.c.44      2   bb    c   44
#cdd.d.3      3  cdd    d    3
```