# Extracting end of string with variable lenght

Tags: r, regex, stringr

Say you have a vector of characters like this:

```
x <- c('file_123',
       'file_456',
       'file_clean_67890',
       '123_file_1234')
```

And you want to extract the end of the string after the last `"_"`. How would you do this? The result I would like is:

```
"123"   "456"   "67890" "1234"
```

If you use `str_split`, you can't get the very last one because they have different lengths:

```
> x %>% str_split(pattern = '_', simplify = T)
     [,1]   [,2]    [,3]  
[1,] "file" "123"   ""    
[2,] "file" "456"   ""    
[3,] "file" "clean" "6789"
[4,] "123"  "file"  "1234"
```

This questions is somewhat duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17215789/extract-a-substring-in-r-according-to-a-pattern) with the difference that since I don't know the number of splits. Also, you could have digit characters before the last underscore, so you can't just detect those.

Comment: Use `TRUE` and `FALSE` instead of `T` and `F`! The latter are *variables* and can be changed in code.

Answer (score 0):

Use str_extract_all from stringr with a regex. See `?regular expression` for information on `[:digit:]`, `+` and `$` metacharacters:

```
str_extract_all(x,"_[[:digit:]]+$")
```

Comment: you can also use R base `sub`: `sub(".*_(\\d+)", "\\1", x)`

Comment: I guess it would be `str_extract_all(x,"[[:digit:]]+$")` because I don't actually want that last `"_"`, but it works. Thanks!