# Insert specific character in front of specific pattern in R

Tags: r, string, character

I want to insert a specific character ("+") in front of the character "b" as part of a string in R. So for example "2b^3" should be converted to "2+b^3" or "200b" to "200+b". How can I achieve this?

Edit:
I have a follow up question to the one before:

I have tried this answer:
[Extract a substring according to a pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17215789/extract-a-substring-according-to-a-pattern)

But it doesn't work for ^:

```
string = "2+b^3"
sub(".*^", "", string)
```

gives me still "2+b^3" and I would like to receive "3".

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution, in `base R`:

```r
gsub("b", "+b", "2b^3")

#> [1] "2+b^3"
```

---

Or using `stringr::replace`:

```r
stringr::str_replace("2b^3", "b", "+b")

#> [1] "2+b^3"
```

Comment: thank you very much, do you have an answer to the follow up question as well? would really appreciate it!

Comment: @Thefourthbird has already offered you a solution!

Answer (score 1):

If the `b` char is always prepended by a digit, you can capture the digits and use the capture group in the replacement.

```
gsub("(\\d)b", "\\1+b", "2b^3")
```

Output ([R demo](https://tio.run/##K/r/P724NElDSSMmJkUzSUlHQSkmxlAbzDBKijNW0vz/HwA))

```
[1] "2+b^3"
```

---

For the second part you have to escape the caret `\^` or else it would denote the start of the string.

```
string = "2+b^3"
sub(".*\\^", "", string)
```

Output ([R demo](https://tio.run/##K/r/v7ikKDMvXcFWQclIOynOWImruDRJQ0lPKyYmTklHQQmIISo0//8HAA))

```
3
```