# Split values present in a cell

Tags: r, excel

I have an excel column called `code` that contains the follwing codes. The codes are stored as text and not values, hence the presence of 0 at the begining of each code.

```
Code
0101016041
0101016041
0101016042
0201016042
0201016043
0101016043
0304046323
0304046324
0304046324
0404046324
0404046324
```

I'd like to split the first two values (01, 02,03 & 04) and store them in a separate column.
How do I do that given that there's do delimiter to separate these values?

Thanks

Comment: left(A1,2) will give the two leftmost characters. Then you can use right() for the rest or even mid() if the number of characters is always the same.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract a substring according to a pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17215789/extract-a-substring-according-to-a-pattern)

Answer (score 2):

So, using Excel:

```
left(A1,2)
```

And:

```
right(A1,8)
```

Or

```
Mid(A1,3,8)
```

You could use mid() for the first two:

```
mid(A1,1,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

`=MID(A1:A11,COLUMN(A:E),2)`

Or `=MID(A1:A11,SEQUENCE(,5),2)` or `=MID(A1:A11,{1,2,3,4,5},2)` in older Excel it requires being entered with `Ctrl+shift+enter`